# Array in array: jq: error (at test.json:91): object ({"locations...) is not valid in a csv row

Tags: json, jq

I want to convert json to csv.

I use tool "jq" for this

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Here json

```
 {
  "total": 2040,
  "created_at": "2022-01-27T09:50:59+0200",
  "project": "my project",
  "issues": [
    {
      "key": "key_1",
      "component": "my_component",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 35,
        "endLine": 35,
        "startOffset": 46,
        "endOffset": 84
      },
      "flows": [],
      "status": "OPEN",
      "creationDate": "2022-01-24T06:42:58+0200",
      "updateDate": "2022-01-24T06:42:58+0200",
      "type": "BUG",
      "scope": "MAIN"
    },
    {
      "key": "key2",
      "component": "my component 2",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 34,
        "endLine": 34,
        "startOffset": 3,
        "endOffset": 52
      },
      "flows": [
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "component": "some component",
              "textRange": {
                "startLine": 35,
                "endLine": 35,
                "startOffset": 3,
                "endOffset": 50
              },
              "msg": "any  message"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "component": "another component",
              "textRange": {
                "startLine": 36,
                "endLine": 36,
                "startOffset": 3,
                "endOffset": 71
              },
              "msg": "message custom"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "component": "Alarm.java",
              "textRange": {
                "startLine": 37,
                "endLine": 37,
                "startOffset": 3,
                "endOffset": 76
              },
              "msg": "message number 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "locations": [
            {
              "component": "Alarm.java",
              "textRange": {
                "startLine": 38,
                "endLine": 38,
                "startOffset": 3,
                "endOffset": 50
              },
              "msg": "message number 3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "my_key3",
      "component": "my component 3",
      "textRange": {
        "startLine": 548,
        "endLine": 548,
        "startOffset": 14,
        "endOffset": 15
      },
      "flows": [],
      "status": "OPEN",
      "creationDate": "2022-01-21T17:16:06+0200",
      "updateDate": "2022-01-21T17:16:06+0200",
      "type": "CODE_SMELL",
      "scope": "LOCAL"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here convert to csv only some flelds:

```
jq -r '.issues[] | [.key ,.component, .textRange[], .status] | @csv' test.json
```

And here result:

```
"1","my_component",35,35,46,84,"OPEN"
"2","my component 2",34,34,3,52,
```

Nice.

Now I want to convert field (array)  **flows**. I try this:

```
jq -r '.issues[] | [.key ,.component, .textRange[], .flows[], .status] | @csv' test.json
```

And here result:

```
"1","my_component",35,35,46,84,"OPEN"
jq: error (at test.json:91): object ({"locations...) is not valid in a csv row
```

How fix convert? Array (**locations**) in array (**flows**)

The result must be like this (first line are fields's names):

```
total,created_at,project,issues,key,component,textRange,startLine,endLine,startOffset,endOffset,status,creationDate,updateDate,type,scope,flows,locations,component,textRange,startLine,endLine,startOffset,endOffset,msg
2040,2022-01-27T09:50:59+0200,my project,,key_1,my_component,,35,35,46,84,OPEN,2022-01-24T06:42:58+0200,2022-01-24T06:42:58+0200,BUG,MAIN,,,,,,,,,
,,,,key2,my component 2,,34,34,3,52,,,,,,,,some component,,35,35,3,50,any  message
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,another component,,36,36,3,71,message custom
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Alarm.java,,37,37,3,76,message number 2
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Alarm.java,,38,38,3,50,message number 3
,,,,my_key3,my component 3,,548,548,14,15,OPEN,2022-01-21T17:16:06+0200,2022-01-21T17:16:06+0200,CODE_SMELL,LOCAL,,,,,,,,,
```

It's important to show values not only `issues` but also fields's values: `total,created_at,project`

Comment: Your update is still unclear. For instance, what should the fourth column (labelled "issues") ever contain? Your sample output always has nothing, thus I cannot deduce what your intentions are (and any code has to be explicit on matters like this).

Comment: @pmf I was updated my post

Comment: Your second update still has only empty values in the fourth column (an this was just an example). Generally speaking, it would be much clearer (and a lot easier for us who are trying to help) if you _tried_ to explain what computations you are seeking to perform, rather than just adding more (obscure to us) data that needs to be disentangled first before anyone could even start to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the objects in `.flows[].locations[]` to be **appended** as separate rows?

```sh
jq -r '.issues[]
  | .key as $key | ., .flows[].locations[]
  | [$key ,.component, .textRange[], .status]
  | @csv
'
```

```
"1","my_component",35,35,46,84,"OPEN"
"2","my component 2",34,34,3,52,
"2","some component",35,35,3,50,
"2","another component",36,36,3,71,
"2","Alarm.java",37,37,3,76,
"2","Alarm.java",38,38,3,50,
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zjnAYuIY-r)

Comment: I was updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need stringify, then you can use **tostring** such as

```
jq -r '.issues[] 
        | [.key ,.component, .textRange[], (.flows[].locations[]|tostring), .status] 
        | @csv'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/V74iqcH7h7)</kbd>

Comment: But it show: 2","my component 2",34,34,3,52,"{""component"":""some component"",""textRange"":{""startLine ...  But is it possible to not show name of fields like: "textRange", "startLine" and so on. To show only values.

Comment: yes, what you need should be the other answer @Alexei

Comment: Ozha. I was updated my post